# How can I set User Defined Build Settings for XCode in premake?

Tags: xcode, premake

I need premake to set the `EXCLUDED_SOURCE_FILE_NAMES` and `INCLUDED_SOURCE_FILE_NAMES` variables for my XCode project. Anybody knows how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

There isn't a way to do that directly, but if you provide more details on what you are trying to achieve there might be a workaround. You are already aware of the excludes() API?

**In response to additional information in comment:** Ah, a unity build then. That isn't directly supported yet, no, though it is coming up quick on the roadmap now. The way most people handle it currently is as a separate project. Not as convenient or elegant, but does allow Debug, Release etc. configurations of the unity build, which can useful too.

Comment: I need a normal configuration in which all source files are compiled. Then I need a bulk configuration in which a single special source file (bulk.cpp), which just includes all other source files, is compiled.

As far as I know, the list of files to be compiled is set in the target section, not in the build configuration section.

Meanwhile, I found a patch which answers my question:
http://sourceforge.net/tracker/?func=detail&aid=3014887&group_id=71616&atid=531880

Haven't tested yet though. I'll post a response if this works.